# Por que "tirinha"?

Tags: significado

[image]

Qual origem da palavra "tirinha"? Tem esse nome por que é uma história em quadrinho de curta metragem ou tem algum outro significado?

Comment: Provavelmente tem origem na palavra "tiragem", que é o nome dado à quantidade de exemplares de uma publicação emitidas/impressas/distribuídas. Então uma tirinha são quadrinhos "pequenos" publicados, pode ser que o nome tenha surgido porque são a parte cômica (geralmente) do jornal e precisa de um nome mais "descontraído" como pode se referir a tiragem de revistas em quadrinhos mas no diminutivo para se referir que elas eram curtas. São apenas palpites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É uma tradução mais ou menos literal da palavra inglesa *strip*, a qual é parte integrante da expressão usual em inglês, *comic strip*, literalmente "tira cômica".

Conferir também o francês *bande dessinée* e o português europeu "banda desenhada", com a mesma implicação de tira, faixa, pedaço retangular de papel cujo comprimento excede bastante a altura.

Comment: Diz-se *tira cómica* também em espanhol, e também já vi em português.